# Why am I getting 'undefined:x:y : property' missing error when running jest tests?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, styled-components

I am using jest & styled-components, or more specifically [jest-styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#jest-integration) for testing.

I have made changes to a component called *FormField*, which used the component *Form*, when running the tests, I am getting the following error.

```
    undefined:42:16: property missing ':'

      31 |     );
      32 |     const tree = component.toJSON();
    > 33 |     expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
         |                  ^
      34 |   });
      35 | 
      36 |   test('update', () => {
```

The jest test is as following

```
  test('with field', () => {
    const component = renderer.create(
      <Grommet>
        <Form>
          <FormField name="test" />
        </Form>
      </Grommet>,
    );
    const tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

I can't pinpoint what the problem is, the changes I made to the component did not show any errors, and I'm getting the same errors in the testing of FormField component.

Comment: My guess is your SASS code for one of those components has a typo (most likely, a missing `:`). See also, issue [#97](https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components/issues/97)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem.
The problem was caused because I did not update the snapshot after the changes I made to the component.

It can be done with

```
jest --updateSnapshot or jest --u
```